# Replacing a value with actual if condition with DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need help with implementing actual if conditions with dataframe. I know the `replace` and `where` functions, but unfortunately I am not directly able to use them.

Basically I want to change value of a column based on whether a folder exists with a UID. If the folder exists in related directory I want to place `yes`, if not, I want to place `no`. For example: if `D:\data\folder\00010002` exists, then `folder` value of the `UID` should be `yes`. Else, it should be `no`. How can I do that?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

d = {'UID': ["00010002", "00010004"], 'folder': ['a', 'a']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for a in d['UID']:
    if os.path.isdir(f'D:\data\folder\{a}'):
        df.loc[df.folder] == 'yes'
    else:
        df.loc[df.folder] == 'no'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['folder'] = df['UID'].apply(lambda uid: 'yes' if os.path.isdir(f'D:\\data\\folder\\{uid}') else 'no')
```

Comment: Would `lambda uid: "yes" if os.path.isdir(f'D:\\data\\folder\\{uid}') else "no"` give the same result and be simpler?

Comment: I checked and gave my upvotes, I tried if the solution would work for a large group of datasheets, it did it very quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! That's awesome! It's about as fast as it can dealing with the filesystem.